# Possible to skip the first property in json object table?

Tags: json, swift, datatable

My function to parse an array of properties to a json object looks like this:

```
var jsonObject = "[{"

        for i in 1...table.count {
            var str = ""
            var insideStr = String()
            for property in properties {
                let filteredTable = table.value(forKey: property) as! [Any]
                insideStr += "\"\(property)\": \"\(filteredTable[i - 2])\","
            }

            let index = insideStr.characters.index(insideStr.startIndex, offsetBy: (insideStr.count - 2))

            insideStr = String(insideStr[...index])
            str += "\(insideStr)}],"
            jsonObject.append(str)
        }
        let index = jsonObject.characters.index(jsonObject.startIndex, offsetBy: (jsonObject.count - 2))
        jsonObject = "\(String(jsonObject[...index]))"
        return jsonObject
        }catch let error { print("\(error)") }
```

My question is, is it possible to skip the first property because it always returns nil data?

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the first property:

```
delete obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
```

otherwise slice like this:

```
Object.entries(obj).slice(1); //array of arrays [key,value], without the first.
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your for loop with a for...in style loop, and then add a where clause to exclude nils since you don't want to risk dealing with them.

```
for tableItem in table where tableItem != nil {
    // Handle json here
}
```

Or, you can use higher order functions to remove all the nils, and then iterate through it like this:

```
table.filter({ $0 != nil }).forEach({ tableItem in // Do stuff with tableItem })
```